# Cannot make a keylistener work

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, keylistener, implements

I have `public class MainFrame extends JFrame implements ActionListener {`

and then later on:

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == e.VK_LEFT) {
        int x = ball.getX() + 1;
         ball.setX(x);
        }
        }
```

however it does not seem to respond when I believe it should.

If I add keylistener instead of actionlister I cannot compile which I can't understand. I'm new to java however i'm used to C#

Comment: It always listens for events, especially from the keyboard.

Comment: Did you search the forum? This question is asked daily. You can start by reading the question found under the `"Related"` heading on the right side of this page. The basic answer is don't use a KeyListener. Instead use `Key Bindings`.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to implement `java.awt.event.KeyListener` not a `ActionListener` to listen for key events.
2. You need to register your listener on the element (frame) you want to listen on by invoking `addKeyListener(...)`.

Example:

```
public class TestFrame extends JFrame implements KeyListener {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        TestFrame testFrame = new TestFrame();
        testFrame.setSize(100, 100);
        testFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        testFrame.addKeyListener(testFrame);
        testFrame.setVisible(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {    }
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {   }
}
```