# Cannot add an object to application

Tags: java, swing, object, addition, keylistener

I'm new to java so forgive me if it's something really obvious.

I'm having trouble with the code below:

```
public class objectgame extends JFrame implements Runnable, KeyListener
{
    public Object object1;


    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        object1 = new Object();
        add(object1);
```

I get the error: `error: non-static variable object1 cannot be referenced from a static context`

However I've tried removing static and everything and it still wont compile because of the code listed above.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: [Probably a 1000 duplicates for this problem](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=referenced+from+a+static+context&oq=referenced+from+a+static+context&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.248j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=2&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8). Have you searched?

Comment: change `public Object object1;` to `public static Object object1;`

Comment: I've done that but then the line: add(object1); wont work

Comment: I swear this [**exact same question**](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22644734/2587435) was asked and answered earlier today by you

Comment: @peeskillet And that too by the same `user`. What a coincidence!!!

Comment: @user3371315, why don't you start accepting previous answers(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22595306/animating-two-images-in-java, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22131146/cannot-make-a-keylistener-work) before asking new questions?

Answer (score 0):

In this code `public Object object1;`  should be `static` otherwise  it can't be accessed in `static` method or you can solve this problem by making `Object object1` a local variable in the `main` method .

Answer (score 0):

try this:
   static public Object object1;

Comment: I'm still getting an error on the line: add(object1);